# Python отличия методов модели регрессии score от функции r2_score

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy

При построении модели хотел сравнивать значения r2_score() - коэффициент детерминации, что и делал, однако при прочтении документации к функциям моделей натолкнулся на такую строку.

> score(self, X, y[, sample_weight])    Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

Получается метод score() тоже возвращает коэффициент детерминации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то я не припомню **метода** `r2_score()`.

[r2_score()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) - это независимая от регрессора функция метрики, а [`regression_class.score()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) - это метод класса, который внутри вызывает метрику `r2_score()`

> Notes
>
> The R2 score used when calling score on a regressor will use
>   `multioutput='uniform_average'` from version 0.23 to keep consistent
>   with metrics.r2_score. This will influence the score method of all the
>   multioutput regressors (except for `multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor`).
>   To specify the default value manually and avoid the warning, please
>   either call `metrics.r2_score` directly or make a custom scorer with
>   metrics.make_scorer (the built-in scorer `'r2'` uses
>   `multioutput='uniform_average'`).

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять различия между методом score() и функцией r2_score().
Если я передам им одинаковые параметры, на выходе я получу одинаковое значение? Что-то типа model.score(X_test,Y_test) и r2_score(model.predict(X_test), Y_test).

Comment: @KordDEM, я думаю вы должны получить одинаковый результат (если учесть замечание о `multioutput='uniform_average'`)